# Replacing a LM741 op amp with higher quality op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, preamp

I am a complete novice with electronics...but i'm looking to build a replica of a discontinued TC Electronic Integrated Preamp. Its a basic line booster with Volume, Bass and Treble but sounds great when you feed it with 18-32volts. The schematics are out there and i'm looking to just copy it and try to build a basic one using a breadboard to begin with. 
I was wondering though would it be possible to use an op amp from something of much higher quality. I wondered if it would be possible to experiment with putting an op-amp from hi end audio gear into it. Something like this for example:
http://www.sonicimagerylabs.com/products/product_images_docs/990Enh_Ticha_Docs/990Enh_Ticha_Datasheet.pdf

Heres the details for the TC Preamp:

[image: Schematic of circuit]

http://www.aronnelson.com/gallery/main.php/v/slackers-stuff/tcpreboardfinal.jpg.html

Comment: Discrete op-amps are a scam to separate audiophools from their money. If you want a very nice low-noise, low-distortion op-amp, put in an LM4562.  Or a very nice inexpensive op-amp that is almost as good NE5532. I'm afraid all of this is pointless in the designed device, with its pointless single-ended BJT front end that negates the use of a low-noise, low-distortion op-amp. Not to mention the single-voltage supply that destroys common-mode rejection.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where the LM741 reference came from.  The schematic you link to shows a TL071, which is a much more appropriate opamp for audio use.  I would stick to the TL071 as designed.

Comment: The LM741 came from the second schematic link.

Comment: @Simple: No, the second schematic, the one you call the "TC Preamp" clearly shows the opamp being a TL071.  I thought that's what you want to build, so I don't see the relevance of the first link anyway.  In any case, build the preamp as designed.  The TL071 should be able to do this job.

Comment: I'm not the OP. And that would be the first schematic, but the second link. The second schematic is not hyperlinked, but is just below it. I've hyperlinked it now.

Answer (score 0):

The components were chosen with the LM741 in mind. They would have to change, too, with the op amp. I would stick with the LM741 and get a working circuit, which, as you mentioned, sounds great. Improvements would involve studying it to find out why the specific components were chosen, then redesigning the whole thing around a current audio op amp. There are many ways to improve this preamp -- the op amp is just the tip of the iceberg! *<sub><sup>(Just don't ask me.)</sup></sub>*